# CSV.parse error undefined method `pos' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001036cb6b0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Maybe it's related to this issue: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/issue/346

But in Rails 3.0.3 (ruby 1.9.2) I can't seem to get CSV.parse to work.

Here is sample code:

```
row_index = 0
CSV.parse(params[:dump][:file]) do |cells|
  column_index = 0
  cells.each do |cell|
    column_index += 1
  end
  row_index += 1
end
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this from the Rails console? Have you tried preventing plugins from loading? How about removing gems? Does what you're trying to do work in regular irb?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks. See answer below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had to do this in Rails 3:

```
data = params[:dump][:file].read
CSV.parse(data)
```

`params[:dump][:file]` is an `ActionDispatch` object and can't be parsed directly by `CSV.parse`.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing

```
CSV.parse(params[:dump][:file].tempfile).each do |row|
    #stuff with row
end
```

At least with Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.2 this works.